# Anyone know how to fix this error on prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

in prestashop 1.5.6 I pushed clear smarty cache... button under admin menu and bang:

```
Fatal error: Cannot call abstract method ControllerCore::init() in /home/xxx/public_html/classes/controller/FrontController.php on line 110
```

I just cleared smarty cache..

thank you

Comment: After clear the smarty cache...did you reboot the server...or the apache service?

Comment: nope, im on shared hosting, but is not first time when I use clear smarty cache

Comment: This error does not make any sense. Take look at your file `/classes/controller/Controller.php`, see a method `init()` and check, whether it is as abstract. CHeck also your `override` directory

Comment: I restored files from backup but error still here, maybe this action modiffied database?

Comment: verry helpfull website...

Answer (score 0):

Remove ***cache/class_index.php*** and reload the page. I hope that should be the issue.